# Instantiating custom classes at runtime of unknown type

Tags: c#, .net

I saw variants of this question before, but didn't find answer yet.

I have a custom class:

```
public class Indicator
{
   public double Value { get; set;}

   virtual public void Calc(val1, val2) {}
}
```

And I have many classes derived from it, such as:

```
class calc_sum : Indicator
{    
   override public void Calc(val1, val2)
   {
     Value=val1+val2;
   }
}
```

Finally, I have a class to hold all "Indicators":

```
class IndicatorCollection
{
  List<Indicator> _collection = new List<Indicator>();

  ...Some other methods here...
}
```

What I need, is to provide a method in the "IndicatorCollection" class which accepts a string based name of a class derived from "Indicator" and add it to the _collection.
i.e:

```
IndicatorCollection.AddIndicator("calc_sum");
```

That way the user can add indicators at runtime (The IndicatorsCollection is binded to a list which displays the Value property of each member).

I hope I was clear enough and that I am taking the right approach. 
Thank you all

**Update:**
The Activator method is exactly what I was looking for, So I'll try to make it more difficult:

After adding the Indicator instance, can IndicatorCollection expose a new Property which is a shortcut to the class's Value property.

i.e:

```
// After adding calc_sum to the collection, The IndicatorCollection class will have the following //property:
public double calc_sum
{
  get { return _collection.Find(i=>i.name=="calc_sym").First().Value;
  // The indicator class also has a public member of "name"
}
```

Comment: Your code will not compile as the `override` and `virtual` keywords cannot be first on the modifier list.

Comment: I'd also make `Indicator` and the `Calc` method abstract based on your example above.

Comment: I don't think your new requirement can be met. It's not possible to add properties to an existing type on the fly using C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Indicator` class and its descendants expose a public parameterless constructor, you can use [Activator.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx) to dynamically instantiate a class from its name at runtime:

```
public class IndicatorCollection
{
    public void AddIndicator(string className)
    {
        _collection.Add((Indicator)
            Activator.CreateInstance(null, className).Unwrap());
    }

    private List<Indicator> _collection = new List<Indicator>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the activator class to instantiate objects based on class name.  Assuming the `calc_sum` indicator exists in an assembly in the bin directory (or other probing paths), you can get an instance of it:

```
var myIndicator = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("calc_sum")) as Indicator;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second requirement (after your update), why not use a `Dictionary<string, Inidicator>` instead of `List<indicator>` to store the names? Maybe you are over complicating your requirements.

```
public class IndicatorCollection
{
    var _dictionary = new Dictrionary<string, Indicator>();

    public void AddIndicator(string className)
    {
        _dictionary.Add(
            className,
            (Indicator)Activator.CreateInstance(null, className).Unwrap()
        );
    }
}
```

and then...

```
public double GetValue(string indicatorName)
{
   return _dictionary[indicatorName].Value;
}
```

Comment: The reason I want it to be a property is: Currently the list is binded to an ItemsCollection. I want instead to bind it to individual items, ie: {Binding IndicatorCollectionInstance.calc_sum}